# Is there a way to animate an application in when the taskbar icon is clicked?

Tags: c#

I'm currently animating my C# application, and I was wondering if there was a way I could play an animation when I press the icon in the taskbar.  Is this possible?

For example, I have it animating when it loads.

```cs
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AnimateWindow(this.Handle, 500, AnimateWindowFlags.AW_CENTER);

}
```

Comment: The best I can think of is `Form.Activated` event, which occurs every time you switch to this form (so via Task Bar, or by clicking on a window, or from code)

Comment: I would recommend against manually adding window animations that aren't already provided by the system. Even though the user can disable such animations (at least as long as you use standard functions), even for users that don't have the animations disabled it's not necessarily any more enjoyable to have an application behave differently from the others.